# how trigger Event for pixijs app on unittest

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, pixi.js

I would like to simulate events for unittest on PIXIJS for testing following:

```
 app.stage.on('mousemove', (moveData)=> {
  if (!isDragging) {
    return;
  }
```

I know that I can create an PIXIJS event like following, but I don't know how pass it to app on test.

```
it('should ', () => {
let e = new PIXI.InteractionEvent();
e.data = new PIXI.InteractionData();
e.data.global.x = 10;
e.data.global.y = 10;});
```

Answer (score 1):

For unit testing, `emit` is as simple as it gets:

```js
app.stage.emit('mousemove', {
    data: {
        global: {
            x: 10,
            y: 10,
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a pixi playground with a complete example:

https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/NXaInXBgi27W8XPy9oCt6